# Writing to file, yet can't find data when I pull the file up from desktop

Tags: c, printf, fopen

I'm running into a rather bizarre problem here. I'm using fopen and fprintf to write a sentence to a file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("wageData.txt","w");
    fprintf(fp, "Hi, I like pie");
    return 0;
}
```

Yet when I open up wageData.txt on the desktop, there is absolutely nothing in it. On the other hand, if I try reading the file, I get the information:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    //FILE *fp;
    //fp = fopen("wageData.txt","r+");
    FILE *c;
    if ((c = fopen("wageData.txt","r")) == NULL)
        printf("File not available");
    else {
        char x[3][6];
        int i = 0;

        while (fgets(x[i], 30, c) != NULL) {
            i++;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            printf("%s\n", x[i]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled, it results in:

```
Hi, I like pie
like pie
ie
[?
 m?iՖ

logout

[Process completed]
```

Can somebody please tell me what is going on here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: char x[**3**][**6**];

Comment: Firstly when calling fgets you should not allow more characters than you have memory. With your code you can only read 3 strings of 6 characters each so you should not pass 30, but 6 and you should not loop until EOF, but only loop 3 times.

Your second loop is printing 6 strings out of a possible list of 3 strings.

You are essentially printing random parts of memory and getting random results exactly as expected.

I think you should use the i, which you were counting to see how many strings were read out when you print. It is probably 0 and nothing was read.

Comment: Dimensions in `char x[3][6];` don't match how you're using `x`, and you'd be writing past the bounds of `x` with `fgets()` if the file had more than 17 chars in it.  And you're reading out of bounds  with your `printf()` loop regardless.  Also, are you sure the file on your desktop is the same file your program writes?  Could there be more than one?

Answer (score 0):

While reading file you can do something like this -

```
   if ((fp = fopen("wageData.txt","r")) == NULL)
              printf("File not available");
   else {
             char x[100];
             //int i = 0;
             while (fgets(x,100, fp) != NULL)
              {
                     printf("%s\n", x);
              }
       }
  fclose(fp);
```

And then if you want to break sentence in number of strings you can make use of `sscanf` -http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sscanf.htm

Answer (score -1):

In your original program, you aren't closing the file. This results in weird things happening (usually stuff doesn't write unless it has to and if you don't close the file, it probably won't write because it thinks that there might be more data and you currently don't have that much stuff).

Ref:
http://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fclose

Comment: On most systems, the file would be closed when the program terminates anyway... and if not closing the file were the problem, there'd be nothing in it when he reads with his second program either.

Comment: see [n1570.pdf](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) **5.1.2.2.3 Program termination** and **7.22.4.4 The exit function**

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364451(v=vs.85).aspx

I wasn't talking about the program doing stuff